# respond to do format Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 Fields like State and Cities. Cities are to be loaded with respect to the corresponding State. And my fields are not purely DropDown. They are like an input field with autocomplete which allows us to select multiple options(refer images..)

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

This is how I load my states.

```
<%= jl.select :state_id,  State.all.map{|j| [j[:name], j[:id]]}, {}, {class: 'select2', multiple: true, 'data-placeholder' => 'Type State to Search'} %>
```

And to load cities I have written jquery which sent an ajax request and then append the response in its success function.

And my controller is like

```
def update_city_select
    @states = State.where(name: params[:name]).order(:id) unless params[:name].blank?    
    @cities = City.where(state_id: @states.first.id).order(:name) unless @states.first.id.blank?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render layout: false }
      format.js
      format.xml
    end
  end
```

And my update_city_select.html.erb is like

```
<%= select_tag 'city_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, "id", "name", @states), {}, {class: 'select2', multiple: true, 'data-placeholder' => 'Type City to Search'} %>
```

Thing is I always gets an error in my terminal..

```
(wrong number of arguments (4 for 1..3)):
    1: <%= select_tag 'city_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, "id", "name", @states), {}, {class: 'select2', multiple: true, 'data-placeholder' => 'Type State to Search'} %>
```

And if I remove {} form update_city_html page it would work fine. But all I get is a simple dropdown list without that input field like alabama california in my 1st image.
Is there any way I can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is to do with how you're rendering your form, not the `respond_to` block in Rails. I see you're using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html):

---

[`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)

It's my belief that your `select_tag` is not being called correctly. This is irrespective of whether you're calling the right `content-type` from `respond_to`

This may seem obvious, but the fact is you're calling `select_tag` independently of your form, and consequently this will be the cause of the issue

---

**options_from_collection_for_select**

Admittedly, I don't have any experience with `select2`, but I've been looking, and I think your problem *might* be to do with your [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select), as well as your `{}`:

```
<%= select_tag 'city_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, "id", "name", @states), {}, {class: 'select2', multiple: true, 'data-placeholder' => 'Type State to Search'} %>
```

I would test passing only id's to the last argument of `options_from_collection_for_select` (to see if your sending whole objects will be an issue for Rails)

---

**select**

As mentioned by [Paul the octopus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_the_Octopus), your calling of `select_tag` basically means you only [have `3` arguments](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) to work with, whereas [`f.select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) has 4:

```
select_tag(name, option_tags = nil, options = {})

select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

The surface-level fix will be to use a `form_builder` object with your new `select` tag, instead of a naked `select_tag`:

```
#update_city_select.html.erb 
<%= form_for @instace_var_for_form do |jl| %>
    <%= jl.select :city,  options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, "id", "name", @states), {}, {class: 'select2', multiple: true, 'data-placeholder' => 'Type State to Search'} %>
<% end %>

#ajax
$(document).on("ajax:success", "select", function(data) {
    //pull select form form
    $("element").append(select);
});
```

Comment: Actually i didn't understand. Can you be more specific.

Comment: Sorrry - I hit submit by accident - I'm working on the answer still!

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):
    1: <%= form_for @instace_var_for_form do |jl| %>
    2:     <%= jl.select :city,  options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, "id", "name"), {}, {class: 'select2', multiple: true, 'data-placeholder' => 'Type State to Search'} %>
    3: <% end %>
getting this error in console :(

Comment: Sorry - I meant to say I used that as a placeholder for your instance variable you used in your form. You need to replace `@instance_var_for_form` with the instance var you used in `@form_for`, and perhaps set that variable again in your ajax action

Answer (score 0):

`select_tag` accepts only 3 arguments. Have a look at its [definition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0c7691f1d43d08f700f1303349e155522c1a22aa/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L124).
So leave it as

```
`select_tag 'city_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, "id", "name", @states), {class: 'select2', multiple: true, 'data-placeholder' => 'Type City to Search'}`
```

Be sure to set the correct format for your ajax request (this should be **jsonp**)

```
$("#your_states_input_id").select2({
  placeholder: "Search for a city",
  ajax: { 
    url: "your_city_url_here",
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  }
});
```

For more info have a look at [select2 ajax example](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#ajax)

Comment: I really like it when someone down vote an answer and doesn't say why he did it.

Comment: you didnt read my question completly.. I can't omit that {}, on dropping dat {} it would just look like a dropdown table. That input field will be missing.

Comment: Look again at select_tag syntax. It accepts 3 arguments not 4.

Comment: so there is no way i can implement this ? :(